# Left Join two pandas dataframes based on 2 nested conditions?

Tags: python, dataframe, merge, conditional-statements

I have two pandas DataFrames. Each has multiple columns that I will need to bring into the final merged dataframe (I can bring all of them in, no need to filter columns).

The first is called je_results. It has around 100k records of journal entries made to our system. The two important columns in je_results are 'USER_ID' (ID of the user who made the entry) and 'ACCTG_DOCUMENT_ENTRY_DATE' (the date the entry was made).

The second is called UII (User ID Information), with around 1850 records. I've already populated UII with only the USERIDs of users who made journal entries. I used unique to get a list and modify the SQL query. The issue is each USER_ID has multiple records in UII, this is because the records have different timeframes, they were active on (Row_Start & Row_End). Luckily, none of these records can have overlapping timeframes.

I need to join the UII row to je_results where the USER_IDs are the same and the ACCTG_DOCUMENT_ENTRY_DATE is between Row_Start & Row_End.

These are the functions I've tried. I wanted to loop through each je_record row, then loop through each UII record row looking for the row where the USER_IDs are the same and ACCTG_DOCUMENT_ENTRY_DATE is between Row_Start and Row_End. The code doesn't throw any errors, but it runs and runs for 45mins but never completes. I'm assuming I got myself stuck in an endless loop.

def my_function(je_results, UII):
# Define empty lists to store the data
results = []

```
# Reset the index of je_results and UII dataframes
je_results = je_results.reset_index(drop=True)
UII = UII.reset_index(drop=True)

# Loop through the rows of je_results
for je_index, je_row in je_results.iterrows():
    # Loop through the rows of UII
    for ui_index, ui_row in UII.iterrows():
        # Check if the USER_ID matches the one from je_results
        if ui_row['USER_ID'] == je_row['USER_ID']:
            # Get the ACCTG_DOCUMENT_ENTRY_DATE from je_results
            date = je_row['ACCTG_DOCUMENT_ENTRY_DATE']
            # Check if the ACCTG_DOCUMENT_ENTRY_DATE is between Row_Start and Row_End
            if date >= ui_row['Row_Start'] and date <= ui_row['Row_End']:
                # If it's between Row_Start and Row_End, create a new row with the information from both dataframes
                merged_row = pd.concat([je_row, ui_row])
                # Add the merged row to the results list
                results.append(merged_row)

# Create a new dataframe with the saved data
merged_df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=je_results.columns.tolist()+UII.columns.tolist())
merged_df = merged_df.reset_index(drop=True)

return merged_df
```

merged_df = my_function(je_results,UII)

This is another version I've tried. It gives 'reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects'.

def my_function(je_results, UII):
# Define empty list to store the data
results = []

```
# Loop through the rows of je_results
for index, row in je_results.iterrows():
    # Find the UII row that matches the conditions
    matched_uii = UII[(UII['USER_ID'] == row['USER_ID']) & (UII['Row_Start'] <= row['ACCTG_DOCUMENT_ENTRY_DATE']) & (UII['Row_End'] >= row['ACCTG_DOCUMENT_ENTRY_DATE'])]
    # Check if any UII row was matched
    if not matched_uii.empty:
        # If a match was found, create a merged row and append it to the results list
        merged_row = pd.concat([row, matched_uii.iloc[0]], axis=0)
        results.append(merged_row)

# Create a new dataframe with the saved data
merged_df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=je_results.columns.tolist()+UII.columns.tolist())
merged_df = merged_df.reset_index(drop=True)

return merged_df
```

merged_df = my_function(je_results,UII)

Answer (score 0):

This should give you a resulting dataframe that has all the rows from je_results and matching rows from UII where the USER_IDs are the same and the ACCTG_DOCUMENT_ENTRY_DATE is between Row_Start & Row_End.

```
import pandas as pd

# UII and je_results are already defined as dataframes
merged_df = pd.merge(je_results, UII, left_on='USER_ID', right_on='USER_ID', how='left')

# filter rows where ACCTG_DOCUMENT_ENTRY_DATE is between Row_Start & Row_End
result = merged_df[(merged_df['ACCTG_DOCUMENT_ENTRY_DATE'] >= merged_df['Row_Start']) & (merged_df['ACCTG_DOCUMENT_ENTRY_DATE'] <= merged_df['Row_End'])]
```

Comment: Deleted first comment. I had tried this before without success. Since you suggested it I checked it again. 
The problem was the data frames themselves. SQL query to create UII had a date filtering that was inaccurate, so there were about 1000 je_results that had no correct dates to filter on. 
Thanks!